# sequential deployment in multiple servers using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jenkins, ansible-playbook

I have 8 servers as(s1,s2,s3...)which are windows servers and an ansible-playbook with tasks in roles.
***How do I configure host inventory and execute all these tasks in s1 then in s2 then in S3...sequentially that is the execution of the playbook in series of servers sequentially.***
I came across some terminology called serial but not sure on implementation
The deployment will be carried using Jenkins.
Any suggestions would be helpful
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To do a set of roles to completion on one host at a time, set [`serial: 1`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) on plays. These batch sizes can be numbers or  percentages.

By default hosts are run in the order they appear in inventory, which would be  [`order: inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory) on the play. Or, you can use alphanumeric collation order with  `order: sorted`.

Comment: I'm using ansible roles and the command I use is like this
ansible-playbook main.yml  --tags 'build-job'. Where do I add serial? Can youplease help on this?

Comment: I added serial:1 but the playbook is taking 2nd hosts initially.
like I have 2 hosts
[werservers]
host1
host2

the order of execution must be
host1 ---------
host2--------

but the execution is on host2 initially then host1.
i have given as order: sorted but the execution is same

Comment: Probably you want `order: inventory` so the inventory defines how it is sorted.  Review `ansible-inventory --list`  with this inventory config, and confirm it is sorted in the correct order.